# Podman sharing one port with every contianer running in a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, podman

On Kubernetes, a typical design paradigm is to share one container on every container running such that they call connect `localhost` with a given port. Then Kubernetes will route that traffic to the container that handles the traffic.

Does podman have this ability, or must you always address the container with the port by its IP address, rather than localhost?

Answer (score 0):

With podman, you can create a “pod” with the [podman pod](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-pod.1.html) command.  For example, use `podman pod create …` command to create a namespace.  You can add containers to this pod and they can use “localhost” in the manner you describe.

I suggest reading [this article about creating pods](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/01/15/podman-managing-containers-pods), which goes into a lot more detail.